# MYSQL Random Alphanumeric Characters Duplicates

Tags: mysql, uuid

How can I make sure that the following code doesn't output the same values twice?

```
SELECT Ucase( MID( UUID(), 1, 8 ) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should always be different, since `UUID()` is designed for that.

### Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid

> UUID()
>
> Returns a Universal Unique Identifier (UUID) generated according to
>   RFC 4122, “A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace”
>   (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt).
>
> A UUID is designed as a number that is globally unique in space and
>   time. Two calls to UUID() are expected to generate two different
>   values, even if these calls are performed on two separate devices not
>   connected to each other.